# Using For Loop To Create New User Control with Datagridview certain Datagridview datasource values not correct

Tags: .net, vb.net, foreach, datagridview

I currently have a section of code that uses a for each loop to cycle through a list which then creates a new user control. The user control accepts the class which the for each loop cycles through and has a Datagridview that is created in the new user control.

The problem I am having is when all is said and done, the datagridview within the user control has a boolean column which is incorrect. When I debug through the initialization of the user control and the datagridview, the value is correct. However when the initialization is complete and the form shows, the boolean is incorrect.

The datagridview datasource is set to a list within the class sent to the constructor.

I have tried alternating the boolean values and the last boolean value of the created user control is correct. But the second one isn't. (I.E.) the input is True, False, True, False. The result in the user control is showing, True, True, True, False.

I'm not sure if it's a referencing issue or what, but I've been trying to figure this out for a while.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
For Each test as OtherClass.Test in assessment.TestList
    EvaluationResultsTable.Controls.Add(New TestEvalutionResult(test))
Next
```

Inside the TestEvalutionResults Class

```
Public Sub New(test as OtherClass.Test)
     With DataGridView1
        .Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "Description"
        ' Description = String
        .Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "SolutionString"
        ' SolutionString = String
        .Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "Required"
        ' Required = Boolean
        .Columns(2).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
        .Columns(3).DataPropertyName = "IsWarranty"
        ' IsWarranty = Boolean
        .Columns(3).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
        ' There is an issue with the required part of the finding being 
        ' over written by the next finding. Seems to be some sort of reference issue.
        .DataSource = test.Findings
        .DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
        'If test.Findings.Count > 0 Then
        '    findingList = test.Findings
        '    For i = 0 To test.Findings.Count - 1
        '        .Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = test.Findings(i).Required
        '    Next
        'End If
End Sub
```

That's the basics of the code.

EDIT 2:
Updated code for clarity? (maybe?)

So within the Test class, there is a list of Findings. 
These findings have the "Description", "SolutionString", "Required", and "IsWarranty" properties which are being used to populate the datagridview.

When the foreach loop executes, I am checking the current finding in findingsList that is being populated into the datagridview. I see the expected value when debugging finding.required

However, as the loop finishes, the result of the findings.required in the datagridview takes the value of the last finding.

I'm going to try and test it with more than one finding in the findingsList. To see if I get different results.

Thanks again.

Comment: I tried to use ESP but the network must be down, so I guess you'll have to do it the old-fashioned way and actually provide the code here.

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: i wouldn't do this. For Each test as Test in class.TestList. Do you actually see how you are using the test word. test is a variable and a type at the same time. You should try to find different name so it's less confusing and easier to debug.

Comment: it's not clear what your issue is. We don't know the type of your columns in the table. You could set the data type for each column but I would look at the table first. which one of the 4 columns isn't supposed to Boolean?

Comment: Both Description and SolutionString are Strings, Required and IsWarranty are both booleans withing the findings class.

Comment: Updated the post for more clarity hopefully.